# Python generate random permutations of number in range

Tags: python, random, permutation, python-itertools

I'm trying to generate a list of 4 permutations of numbers from 1 to 8.

```
import random
# initialize a population of permutation
def permutation (pop_size, chrom_length):

    population = []

    #code begin



    #code end
    return population
```

The pop_size variable is the length of the list, and chrom_length is the length of each permutation

Comment: Your post is missing an actual question. What exactly do you need help with? Is this a homework problem where you aren't allowed to use the standard library? Are you just looking for a standard library function to calculate permutations? Please edit your post so that it's clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at python's [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) module :).

You could attempt something like:

```py
import itertools

def permutation(pop_size, chrom_length):
    return itertools.permutation(pop_size, chrom_length)
```